# matlab - how to display multiple images horizontally with a scrollbar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a set of 100 images that are saved in a cell array and I want to display them all in one figure.
Ofcourse, if I only use the "subplot" function, they will all be displayed quite tiny..
example:

```
for i=1:100
  subplot(1,100,i);
  imshow(images{i});
end
```

Is there any way to make a figure with all of the images in it but with a scroll bar? (so that they'll be displayed in a normal size..)

Answer (score 0):

If your images are small enough, you could concatenate them horizontally and plot one image:

```
fullim = cat(2, images{:});
imshow(fullim)
```

if they're not small, you might try to look up the [publishing platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923422/matlab-how-to-display-multiple-images-horizontally-with-a-scrollbar/20924179#comment31417854_20924179) in combination with your for loop. It will dump the images to an html page without much effort on your part, which should sort-of achieve what you need.

edit: from [Notlikethat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156750/notlikethat), look into `imscrollpanel`

Comment: Furthermore, by catting them together and using an `imscrollpanel` you could probably hack together the desired result. Or does `imshow` do that itself nowadays?